# How to list files of a Debian package without install

Tags: debian, dpkg

This command can only list contents of installed packages,

```
dpkg -L PACKAGENAME
```

but how to list contents of a non-installed package, to preview/examine the package?

Comment: Similar on Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package

Answer (score 461, accepted):

`dpkg -c` (or `--contents`) lists the contents of a .deb package file (It is a front-end to `dpkg-deb`.)

```
dpkg -c package_file.deb
```

To work directly with package names rather than package files, you can use `apt-file`. (You may need to install the `apt-file` package first.)

```
sudo apt-file update        
apt-file list package_name
```

As stated in the first comment, apt-file lists contents for packages in your already-configured Apt repositories. It is irrelevant whether any particular package is or is not installed.

Comment: apt-file also needs to be updated (`sudo apt-file update`), and only lists contents for packages in your already-configured Apt repositories.

Comment: @quackquixote: In Ubuntu 12.04 it's automatic

Comment: The Apt-file answer assumes that your package is coming from a configured repository instead of a `.deb` file you have downloaded separately.  The original question is ambiguous though.

Comment: @confiq, not by my testing.  I'm running 12.04.4 and it still says "E: The cache is empty. You need to run 'apt-file update' first."

Comment: `apt-file list` doesn't work for me.

Comment: Per @eskhool - Incorrect that apt-file update is not needed in Ubuntu...as of Ubuntu 14.04 this is still required

Comment: To show the package's description and controls, ar p NAME.deb control.tar.gz | tar xOvz ./control

Comment: @icando `apt-file find` works, but `apt-file list` does not. Strange program.

Answer (score 61):

Use `--contents` instead of `-L`:

```
dpkg --contents PACKAGENAME
```

When used in this manner, `dpkg` acts as a front-end to `dpkg-deb`, so use `man dpkg-deb` to see all the options.

You can also use an archive browser to view the package contents.

Comment: This doesn't work unless I installed it first and then uninstall it.

Comment: it should work fine if you give it a .deb file as an argument (instead of PACKAGENAME, give it PACKAGE-DEB-FILE).

Comment: This answer is wrong. You have to have the package installed first. If you don't have it installed, then you don't have a .deb file.

Comment: This command works for me. For example, I downloaded google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb from Google. Then issued the command: `dpkg --contents google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` and it listed out all the files it will install (mostly to `/opt/google/chrome`), none of which are currently installed on my system as I type this. (I'm running Xubuntu 11.10 if that matters.)

Comment: @Neil, the answer is not wrong. Just because you have a deb file, doesn't mean it's installed. apt-file needs the entire build-essential package. O.O

Comment: Works great for me, and does not require the installation of the full build-essential package, as required by the accepted answer.

Comment: Get the .deb file with `apt-get download`, e.g.:  `apt-get download apt-file; dpkg -c apt-file*.deb; rm apt-file*.deb`.

Answer (score 28):

`dpkg --contents` will let you look at the uninstalled package. If the .deb is not on your system yet, do

```
apt-get --download-only install pkgname
```

The package will get downloaded to `/var/cache/apt/archives` but not installed.

Comment: Can I just list the contents without download it? If I'm on a very slow connection, and if the package is too large to download. 
If the .deb file has a file header where contents list goes, I guess download the whole package maybe not necessary. Is this possible?

Comment: The --download-only does not work well when a conflicting package is already installed. It will want to remove the conflicting package, when when --download-only is supplied.

Answer (score 18):

The best way would be to browse directly the package repository:

`https://packages.debian.org/[distro name]/all/[package name]/filelist`

Example:

https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/all/transmission-common/filelist

Comment: And to avoid leaving the terminal, you can use e.g. `lynx -dump -nolist http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/all/transmission-common/filelist | grep ^/` (provided you have `lynx` installed).

Answer (score 12):

I took [@baldoz's http idea](https://superuser.com/questions/82923/how-to-list-files-of-a-debian-package-without-install#602527) and generalized it for Ubuntu and Debian, added a little `sed` and wrapped it in a bash function one-liner:

```
function deb_list () { curl -s $(lsb_release -si | sed -e 's Ubuntu https://packages.ubuntu.com ' -e 's Debian https://packages.debian.org ')/$(lsb_release -sc)/all/$1/filelist | sed -n -e '/<pre>/,/<\/pre>/p' | sed -e 's/<[^>]\+>//g' -e '/^$/d'; }
```

Usage:

```
$ deb_list curl
/usr/bin/curl
/usr/share/doc/curl/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/curl/copyright
/usr/share/doc/curl/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/curl.1.gz
```

Same function on multiple lines:

```
function deb_list () {
    curl -s $(lsb_release -si \
                | sed -e 's Ubuntu https://packages.ubuntu.com ' \
                      -e 's Debian https://packages.debian.org '
              )/$(lsb_release -sc)/all/$1/filelist \
      | sed -n -e '/<pre>/,/<\/pre>/p' \
      | sed -e 's/<[^>]\+>//g' -e '/^$/d';
}
```

Explained:

1. lsb_release -si returns "Ubuntu" or "Debian" replace that with the base url `https://packages.ubuntu.com` or `https://packages.debian.org`
2. lsb_Release -sc returns the codename (e.g. "trusty", "sid", etc) use that to build the full URL: `https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/curl/filelist`
3. Fetch that URL with curl and pipe the html through three sed commands. First captures only the file list (what's between `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags); second strips out any html tags; third removes any blank lines.

Note: It doesn't search PPAs, alternate apt sources repos and only queries official packages available for the release of debian/ubuntu you are running.

Comment: Do i need ruby to run it?

Comment: @Anwar, I'd initially used Ruby because I was lazy and multiline regexes suck in sed/awk/grep.  But I've rewritten it to use two sed commands, no Ruby required.

Comment: Nice! This is the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 9):

For all those people who might still googling this issue at Jan 2017, you can have some cool stuff with recent versions of apt and dpkg in Debian 8.5 without downloading anything.

**List Contents of Deb File Without Download:**

First locate the full url of the deb file :

```
root@debian:apt-get --print-uris download yade
'http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/y/yade/yade_2016.06a-7_amd64.deb' yade_2016.06a-7_amd64.deb 1621148 SHA256:26c0d84484a92ae9c2828edaa63243eb764378d79191149970926aa3ec40cdd4
```

PS: --print-uris switch prints the url of deb package but deb is not downloaded.

Then display contents of deb package without downloading it:

```
root@debian:curl -sL -o- "http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/y/yade/yade_2016.06a-7_amd64.deb" |dpkg-deb -c /dev/stdin
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-12-10 22:18 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-12-10 22:18 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-12-10 22:18 ./usr/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x root/root     13184 2016-12-10 22:18 ./usr/bin/yade
.........................more files listed bellow ......................
```

PS: Same result can be achieved with

```
root@debian:dpkg -c <(curl -sL -o- "http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/y/yade/yade_2016.06a-7_amd64.deb")
```

**Extract a file from the above deb package , without download.**
For example we want to read man page of package yade without installing this package and without even downloading the deb package.

Filename of man page inside deb package as advised by `dpkg -c` is `./usr/share/man/man1/yade.1.gz`

To read man page on the fly:

```
root@debian:curl -sL -o- "http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/y/yade/yade_2016.06a-7_amd64.deb" |dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile /dev/stdin |tar -xO ./usr/share/man/man1/yade.1.gz |man /dev/stdin
```

man page is displayed correctly using man application.

PS: Above pipes does not work with ar command.

```
root@debian:apt --version --> apt 1.4~beta2 (amd64)
root@debian:dpkg --version --> Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.18.18 (amd64).
root@debian:man --version --> man 2.7.6.1
root@debian:tar --version --> tar (GNU tar) 1.29
```

Comment: This description works for systems that use only "apt" and don't have the older "apt-x" commands available!

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
apt-get download packages-name
dpkg --contents *.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems it's not possible before installing it first or extracting the list from `.deb` file.

Try the following command:

```
dpkg --contents <(curl -s $(apt-get install --yes --no-download --reinstall --print-uris language-pack-en | tail -n1 | grep -o "http[^']\+"))
```

Change `language-pack-en` with your package name.

It basically reads `.deb` file extracted via `curl` and run `dpkg --contents FILE` on it.

---

You can also check the content without downloading the package file.

So if you know the URL of `.deb` file, the following shell command will list all the package files:

```
dpkg -c <(curl -sL "http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/avis/avis_1.2.2-4_all.deb")
```

<sup>Curl params: `-s` - silent, `-L` - follow moved links.</sup>

If you don't know the URL, fetch by: `apt --print-uris`, e.g.

```
apt --print-uris install avis | grep avis
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, although not exactly a way to directly list the files in a deb package, you could go to https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages, do a search for the desired package, then near the bottom of the ensuing page, click on the **list of files** link found against the desired architecture. The ensuing page gives you a nice listing of the files that the installation of said package will place into your system.