# How to list files installed by an apt-get package?

Tags: package-management, apt-get, installation-package

This problem reoccurs to me every so often, and neither google nor man pages ever helped me to resolve it. The question is, how can I ask apt-get or his friends (apt-file or apt-cache) to give me a list of files installed by a given package? Say I just installed ivy and I want to find .jar, which must have come with it. `locate ivy` will return a lot info about kivy and other similarly named packages/files. Same problem with `apt-file list`. `apt-cache show` won't be too helpful either -- it gives a lot of info about the package, but none about it's files.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I just found the answer: it should be `dpkg -L PACKAGENAME` as in question:  http://superuser.com/questions/82923/how-to-list-files-of-a-debian-package-without-install. I find it quite confusing to tell when I should use apt-get, and when I should go for dpkg. Once and for all it's clear to me that it's dpkg in this case.

Comment: apt is about finding the packages to install (including their dependencies), dpkg knows about the contents of packages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After you install a .deb package (regardless of source – `apt` or local), it's managed by `dpkg`:

```
dpkg -L packagename
```